# sumif (data was entered on a monday)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to have a function in Google Sheets that adds up values from a range if the were entered on a Monday. This is what I have right now, but it adds up to 0 all the time:

=sumif(B6:B20, WEEKDAY(2),C7)

Can someone tell me how to determine what day of the week a number cell was added on, and then add up all the numbers added on that day so I can put the sum in a different cell? (For example, the numbers in the range were added on various days of the week, and I want to add up all the numbers that were added on Monday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming column B is the column to sum and column C has the dates try:

```
=sumproduct(weekday(C2:C) = 2,B2:B)
```